# Bottle micro framework suddenly crash

Tags: python-2.7, bottle, socketserver

i have web app that i have developed using bottle micro framework.
However it crash a lot and all of them suddenly without any action ( without using the web app) . So i have reviewed the logs file and find the following errors (i have no idea what the causation of these errors):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hamoud/lib/python2.7/bottle.py", line 2699, in run
    server.run(app)
  File "/home/hamoud/lib/python2.7/bottle.py", line 2385, in run
    srv = make_server(self.host, self.port, handler, **self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 144, in make_server
    server = server_class((host, port), handler_class)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 419, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 48, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
    SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 430, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

**and**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interface.py", line 29, in <module>
    run(host="localhost", port=32471, reloader=True, debug=True)
  File "/home/hamoud/lib/python2.7/bottle.py", line 2657, in run
    os.utime(lockfile, None) # I am alive!
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/bottle.gQmJc8.lock'
```

However the second error doesn't crash the application ( application would continue working ) but for the first one it's require manual work ( run the app again ).

*i could schedule task using cron job to run the application when it's crash. but i'd like to know what's the problem in my app.*

Comment: Which version of Bottle are you using?

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas come to mind:

1. Could there be another program on your machine (e.g., a cron job) that is deleting files from /tmp?
2. Are you using the latest version of Bottle?  (From the line number in your stacktrace, it looks like you might not be.)
3. If nothing else works, try running without `reloader=True` (or use `reloader=False`).  I looked at the Bottle code, and that change should at least work around the problem, even though we don't know the cause (yet).

Hope that helps.